# Can I run one KeyQuencer Macro from inside of another?

Tags: automation, classic-mac-os

> KeyQuencer is a macro/automation app for Classic Mac System 7.

I have a bunch of Macros already defined and I'd like to call Macro A from Macro B.

Possible workarounds I've dismissed out of preference:

- duplicate the code from A into B
- put all code in external text files (`Open` allows you to use the contents of a text file as the macro)

Is there a way to easily call one Macro from inside of another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe this but the answer is so obvious I'm embarrassed.

Call the second macro from the first *using it's hotkey*!